# With MySQL Cannot get to have separated values from sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get pageviews for the last 30 days. And pageviews total. But for some reason I get the same value for both. So it's merging the values some how.

```
SELECT p.ID, 
       p.post_title post_title,
       p.post_date post_date, 
       SUM(gvd.unique_pageviews) total_unique_pageviews, 
       SUM(gvd.pageviews) total_pageviews,
       thirty_days_views.unique_pageviews thirty_days_views_unique_pageviews,
       thirty_days_views.pageviews thirty_days_views_pageviews
FROM wp_posts as p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as pm on pm.post_id = p.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_google_views_daily gvd ON gvd.post_id = p.ID
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT p.ID,
                  SUM(gvd.unique_pageviews) unique_pageviews,
                  SUM(gvd.pageviews) pageviews
           FROM wp_posts p
           INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as pm on pm.post_id = p.ID
           LEFT JOIN wp_google_views_daily gvd ON gvd.post_id = p.ID
           WHERE
                pm.meta_key = 'template_style'
           AND  pm.meta_value = 'list'
           AND  p.post_status = 'publish'
           AND  p.post_password = ''
           AND  p.post_date >= DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day))
                                GROUP BY p.ID
                                ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
          ) thirty_days_views ON thirty_days_views.ID = p.ID
WHERE
    pm.meta_key = 'template_style'
AND pm.meta_value = 'list'
AND p.post_status = 'publish'
AND p.post_password = ''
GROUP BY 
    p.ID
ORDER BY 
    p.post_date DESC
```

How can I get values that are not affected by the other sub query? So that I get total pageviews and pageviews for the last 30 days?

Comment: add `GROUP BY p.post_date` to the query

Comment: It does not change anything.

Comment: add it in the inner query as well, because unless you have it, you are doing the same calculation

Comment: I did that also. I kept the p.ID: GROUP BY p.ID, p.post_date. The reason is I am trying to get the pageviews per p.ID.

Comment: can you please post a sql fiddle for this?

Comment: as vkp said you could create a sqlfiddle like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c2bd/3)

Comment: please go standard. 99% of the time, when people are not grouping by all selected fields it means they are doing it wrong. There are very rare cases where it is necessary and yours doesn't seem to be. Go to sqlfiddle as suggested, select ORACLE instead of mysql and make your query work using plain sql. If it does, paste it into your mysql editor and try it there.

Answer (score 0):

I review the query and look very complex just to calculate the number of views. Without a fiddle i can recommend simpify the problem to the basic data need.

My guess is because you are calculating `total_unique_pageviews`and `thirty_days_views_unique_pageviews` together

And your internal **left join** include a (select filter by date) you outer select will also calculate  `thirty_days_views_unique_pageviews`.

I suggest you calculate a query for 30 day another for whole data and compare the results. Then try to join both if need it. Divide and Conquer.

Answer (score 0):

Someone I work with helped me. Here is the solution:

```
SELECT
    p.ID, 
    p.post_title post_title,
    p.post_date post_date, 
    all_days_views.unique_pageviews total_unique_pageviews,
    all_days_views.pageviews total_pageviews,
    thirty_days_views.unique_pageviews thirty_days_views_unique_pageviews,
    thirty_days_views.pageviews thirty_days_views_pageviews
FROM 
    wp_posts as p
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as pm on pm.post_id = p.ID and pm.meta_key = 'template_style' and pm.meta_value = 'list'
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            post_id,
            SUM(unique_pageviews) unique_pageviews,
            SUM(pageviews) pageviews
        FROM 
            wp_google_views_daily
        GROUP BY post_id
    ) all_days_views ON all_days_views.post_id = p.ID
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            post_id,
            SUM(unique_pageviews) unique_pageviews,
            SUM(pageviews) pageviews
        FROM 
            wp_google_views_daily
        WHERE
            date >= DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day))
        GROUP BY post_id
    ) thirty_days_views ON thirty_days_views.post_id = p.ID
WHERE
    p.post_status = 'publish' AND
    p.post_password = ''
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```